# Platform IO : ESPAsyncWebServer library gives error when included

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, esp8266, esp32, platformio

I am using platform IO on VS Code. This library used to work the last time I used it which was 5 months ago. Now I am doing a new project, and when I include it like this in the platform.ini file:

```
platform = espressif32
framework = arduino
board = esp32doit-devkit-v1
monitor_speed = 115200

lib_deps =
  # RECOMMENDED
  # Accept new functionality in a backwards compatible manner and patches
  ottowinter/ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome @ 1.3.0}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
In file included from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\SPIFFSEditor.h:3:0,
                 from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\SPIFFSEditor.cpp:1:
.pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:27:16: fatal error: FS.h: No such file or directory

************************************************************
* Looking for FS.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:FS.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:FS.h
*
************************************************************

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib47d\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\SPIFFSEditor.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\AsyncEventSource.h:35:0,
                 from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\AsyncEventSource.cpp:21:
.pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:27:16: fatal error: FS.h: No such file or directory

************************************************************
* Looking for FS.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:FS.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:FS.h
*
************************************************************

compilation terminated.
In file included from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\AsyncWebSocket.h:32:0,
                 from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\AsyncWebSocket.cpp:22:
.pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:27:16: fatal error: FS.h: No such file or directory

************************************************************
* Looking for FS.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:FS.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:FS.h
*
************************************************************

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib47d\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\AsyncEventSource.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\WebHandlers.cpp:21:0:
.pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\ESPAsyncWebServer.h:27:16: fatal error: FS.h: No such file or directory

************************************************************
* Looking for FS.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:FS.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:FS.h
*
************************************************************

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib47d\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\AsyncWebSocket.cpp.o] Error 1
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib47d\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\WebHandlers.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\WebRequest.cpp:21:0:
.pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\ESPAsyncWebServer.h:27:16: fatal error: FS.h: No such file or directory

************************************************************
* Looking for FS.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:FS.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:FS.h
*
************************************************************

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib47d\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\WebRequest.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from .pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\WebResponses.cpp:21:0:
.pio\libdeps\esp32doit-devkit-v1\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\src\ESPAsyncWebServer.h:27:16: fatal error: FS.h: No such file or directory

************************************************************
* Looking for FS.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:FS.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:FS.h
*
************************************************************

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\lib47d\ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome\WebResponses.cpp.o] Error 1
============================================================================================= [FAILED] Took 4.93 seconds =============================================================================================
Der Terminalprozess "C:\Users\User\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe 'run'" wurde mit folgendem Exitcode beendet: 1.

Das Terminal wird von Aufgaben wiederverwendet, drücken Sie zum Schließen eine beliebige Taste.
```

I cant solve the problem but it seems a file "FS.h" is missing. How can I solve this? I have been working on it for an hour now.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone going through the same problem:

Adding "lib_ldf_mode=deep" in the .ini file resolves the issue.